# While attempting to traverse relationships, my entity framework table objects are null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following tables represented in my Entity Framework diagram (.edmx file)

```
Users
 - UserID
 - Username
 - UserGroupID

Groups
 - GroupID
 - GroupName
```

In my code, I retrieve a valid instance of the User object and I'm trying to traverse the relationship to get to the Groups table, to retrieve the GroupName, however everytime, the Groups object is null. The UserGroupID exists in the Groups table, so i'm not sure why this is.

The Visual Studio intellisense knows the relationship exists and allows me to attempt it, but at runtime, the 'Groups' instance is null.

```
  Users users= (Users)e.Row.DataItem;
  string groupName = users.Groups.GroupName;
```

In that case, Groups is null and i'm not sure why.  What are the possible causes?

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to access Groups from within a databound event and the Groups data was not loaded before you binded it. You most likely need to "include" Groups like below.

```
var users = entity.Users.include("Groups").where(x => x.UserID == 20);
```

Comment: Thank you, between the documentation John listed and your answer, I was able to learn the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read this, Entity doesn't seem to act the same as Linq-To-SQL when it comes to Lazy Loading

http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Entity_Framework_and_Lazy_Loading.aspx

How to load related items: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. Reading through them!

Answer (score 0):

probably the lazy loading is disabled.

add the below line when you initialize the context

```
context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

anyway you should think about what strategy you want to use to pull date from your DB